# How to create four block using flex?

Tags: css

I have tried to create four blocks with the same width:

```
1    2 


3    4

<div class="blocks">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>

.block {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo** :

```css
.item {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
   }

   .group{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
   }
```

```html
  <div class="group">
   <div class="item">1</div>
   <div class="item">2</div>
  </div>
                
  <div class="group">
   <div class="item">3</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
```